# Duplicate YouTube iframe embed video playback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube-api, html5-video, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using [react-youtube](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-youtube) (essentially [YouTube iframe embed API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)) in order to render a video player in my web app.

My web app opens a popup window on load, using `window.open()`. It's the same origin so both windows can interact by code and I can manipulate the popup DOM.

I want to clone the original video (video A) from the base web app player, to a separate `<video>` element, located in the popup window (video B), so that it will correspond to all the user actions in the original video player (play, pause, seek, change quality, etc).

I know it can be done by duplicating the whole player and using the `onPlay`, `onPause` and other callbacks to trigger the same actions in the second player - but the ideal solution for me would be to just clone the video output itself.
Obviously cloning by drawing with a Canvas is not a good solution.

I also tried using [player.getIframe()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Accessing_and_Modifying_DOM_Nodes) and to the `<video>` element using `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")`,
(to then capture its stream), but then I'm getting:
`SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame`.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to clone the video output?

Comment: @weltschmerz I want the user to be able to screen share the video output without showing his actions (like play/pause/seek etc). It's out of scope to explain the full use-case but this would solve my problem completely.

Comment: Would simply hiding the buttons in the player and displaying custom buttons elsewhere be an option for you?

Comment: @weltschmerz I need to replicate all the actions the user is doing on video A (controller), onto video B (broadcast) - so hiding the controls on video B would be beneficial, but I would still need to implement callbacks for every action to trigger the same action on video B (onPlay, onPause, etc). That's why I wanted to check if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: Are video A and video B to be shown in different windows/machines?

Comment: @yunzen Same browser, but video B is in a popup window opened from the window of video A (using `window.open()`). It's the same origin so both windows can interact by code.

Comment: That's an information, you should put in your question

Comment: So basically what you want is two players which share the same "state".  That's a bit hard as a lot of the state is internal to the embedded object.  I think you would want to listen to `onStateChange` and then call methods to make changes to the second video in response to state changes of the first.  And make sure that there is some check/stop condition so that they don't just update each other back and forth to infinity.

Comment: @LindaPaiste IIUC, `onStateChange` applies to the player state e.g play, pause, finished, buffering, etc - but it won't be relevant for seeking or skipping time. Also won't apply quality change (only through `onPlaybackQualityChange`). So using `onStateChange` will consolidate some of the other function like `onPlay`, `onPause`, etc, but will still require some more hooks to complete the task. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [captureStream()](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/#dom-htmlmediaelement-capturestream) - it captures a MediaStream from one `<video>` element, so you can set it as the srcObject of another `<video>` element.

See this [demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-video/) and [article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/capture-stream)

Comment: It's a cool idea, the problem is that the video is inside the iframe which is a different origin, so when I try to capture its stream using `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")`, I'm getting: `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Answer (score -1):

You can use local storage for that.

```js
/* First create a click event to save the command to local storage */
$(".test-btn").click(function() {
  let action = $(this).data("action");
  localStorage.setItem('vid_state', action);
});


/* on the other window listen for the change in storage */
$(window).on('storage', function(e) {
  let storageEvent = e.originalEvent;
  if (storageEvent.key == 'vid_state') {
    let action = localStorage.getItem('vid_state');
    console.log(action);
    $("#vid").html(action);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="test-btn" data-action="play">play</button>
<button class="test-btn" data-action="stop">stop</button>

<div id="vid">Current Play State</div>
```

Comment: The issue is not sending the events - as I said, this is possible with the API (`onPlay`, `onPause`, etc - but not what I'm looking for

Comment: I understand. I don't think that is possible though.